# In Java, how can I use .equalsIgnoreCase to apply to multiple strings?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

In Java, how can I use `equalsIgnoreCase` to apply to multiple strings?
I am new to Java and I want the user to enter *a* or *c* or *e* in either lowercase or uppercase.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect your possibilities with the logical OR operator (`||`):

```
if ("a".equalsIgnoreCase(string)
 || "c".equalsIgnoreCase(string)
 || "e".equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
    // Valid string
} else {
    // Invalid string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> String equalsIgnoreCase()

This method compares the two given strings on the basis of content of the string irrespective of case of the string. It is like equals() method but doesn't check case. If any character is not matched, it returns false otherwise it returns true.

As the example

```
 public class EqualsIgnoreCaseExample{  
       public static void main(String args[]){  
         String s1="java";  
         String s2="java";  
         String s3="JAVA";  
         String s4="python";  

         System.out.println(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2));//true because content and case both are same  
         System.out.println(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s3));//true because case is ignored  
         System.out.println(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s4));//false because content is not same  
    }}
```